# Relax calculation in Wien2k

Tags: cell-optimization, wien2k

Can someone help me with the steps to take to perform Relax calculation of a structure in WIEN2k? Then further what to keep in mind while performing strain calculation on the structure for the relax calculation part.
I have understood the volume optimization process. So, at which step do I insert the relax calculations?